# jQuery Mobile doesn't fire events in home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I have a project with PhoneGap and jQueryMobile, using a multi-page template. On the home page the `pageshow`, `pageinit`, `pagecreate`, `pagebeforeshow` events don't fire. I have tried a couple of possible solutions.

Solution 1:

```
$('#home').on("pageshow", function(e) { ... }
```

With this solution, when I change to the second page and return to the home page, the event fires, but not the first time the application loads.

Solution 2:

```
var selector = ':jqmData(role=page)';
$('body').on("pageshow", selector,function(e) { ... }
```

I got Solution 2 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240408/jquery-mobile-pageshow-event-is-not-firing-on-first-page), but it doesn't work for me.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution to this, is create another page first and this redirect to home page with $.mobile.changePage('#home',{transition:'none'}), this page make all the init functions.

With this the home page fire all the events.

Answer (score 0):

`pagebeforeshow`, `pageshow`, and other collections are empty when the first page is transitioned in during the application startup.

> Note that this collection is empty when the first page is transitioned
>   in during application startup.

Read up on the docs: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Ok, thanks. I read that pagebeforeshow, pageshow is empty when the first page is transitioned. But exists any event that fire when the first page is load, or before load?    `pageinit`, `pagecreate` and `pageload` neither works.